# select2 jquery to show image in tooltip on hover in option

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Need to show data-id value for each option on hover in a tooltip

```
 <select id="example">
   <option value="AA" data-id="143">AA</option>
    <option value="BB" data-id="344">BB</option>
    <option value="CC" data-id="773">CC</option>
 </select>
```

I am using select2 https://select2.github.io/examples.html
Please help!!!

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: i tried with but not able to find 
$("#example").select2();

$('#example').on('change', function () {
    $('#theAnswer').text($('#example option:selected').attr('data-id'));
});

Answer (score 4):

You should either rename `data-id` to `title`, or run the following before your `$("#example").select2();`:

```
$("#example option").attr('title', function () {
  return $(this).attr('data-id');
});
```

Comment: I need this in a tooltip

Comment: This WILL get you the data-id in a tooltip. Just hover above the option and you'll see it. If you want a better-looking tooltip you might want to look into adding [jQuery UI's tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) as well (one simple command on your initialization will do the trick).